# Multithreaded access to JDBC connection for only select case

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

If I assign the same connection to multiple threads which only executes select statements(no CRUD), is this scenario thread safe ? Each thread creates its own preparedstatement from the same connection and executes it.
Although it seems thread safe since each thread works its own instance of resultsets and prepared statement objects, they are still using the same connection to the database. I am specifically interested in Oracle JDBC driver behavior.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle docs does not prohibit multi-threaded access. Instead they allow it with the statement "If multiple threads must share a connection, use a disciplined begin-using/end-using protocol."

I think this caution may be due to problematic cases when one thread insert/updates and commit/rollsback while the other thread also inserts/updates its own data and issues a commit or rollback

But, in the original poster's case,all threads only issue select statements... still the resultset.next() will travel to database to retrieve the rows using the same tcp/ip stream to database...which is where the confusion begins...

The behaviour is undefined for 'select-only' case.

Answer (score 2):

I Googled artound and found this:

> "Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference"
>   JDBC and Multithreading
>
> "The Oracle JDBC drivers provide full support for, and are highly optimized for, applications that use Java multithreading. Controlled serial access to a connection, such as that provided by connection caching, is both necessary and encouraged. However, Oracle strongly discourages sharing a database connection among multiple threads. Avoid allowing multiple threads to access a connection simultaneously. If multiple threads must share a connection, use a disciplined begin-using/end-using protocol."

Also bear in mind that when you do update the database, you would need to read from your update connection for transaction isolation to work properly.

As far as I'm aware, getting a connection from a pool is a relatively cheap process.

--EDIT

If you are worried about the number of connections to the server have a look at "Oracle connection mananger"

"Oracle Connection Manager enables large numbers of users to connect to a single server by acting as a connection concentrator to "funnel" multiple client database sessions across a single network connection."

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that the jdbc spec requires Connections to be thread-safe (but not Statements/ResultSets), so this will work.  However, some jdbc driver implementations are less efficient with shared Connections, so you should definitely test whether you are getting decent performance.  if not, you may need to switch to multiple Connections.

Comment: Microsoft's is for sure.  It makes one of our other devs here nervous, but the MS docs say it's fine and I've been doing it for awhile with no problem.  Oracle's docs make me question it, but it sounds like perhaps they're just being cautious.